# Windows registry - block specific devices

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I want my application sometimes to block plugging in new devices except usb mass storage and usb camera and sometimes not to block anything.

I have found information how to allow installing only specific hardware.
I have made simple registry file which does this (*.reg):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions]
"AllowDeviceClasses"=dword:00000001
"DenyUnspecified"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions\AllowDeviceClasses]
"**DelVals."=" "
"1"="{4d36e970-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"
"2"="{71a27cdd-812a-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}"
"3"="{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"
"4"="{4d36e96a-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"
"5"="{6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}"
"6"="{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}"
```

Unfortunately this is not exactly what I am looking for.

I can dynamically change `DenyUnspecified` but once new hardware is installed and `DenyUnspecified` is changed to `00000001` I can replug this hardware and use it without restrictions.

Is there other policy which will be preventing connecting new hardware instead of just installing?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are trying to disable USB devices within the registry? You can disable USB devices with GPO which is much more easy and managable.
Take a look at this link: http://prajwaldesai.com/how-to-disable-usb-devices-using-group-policy/

Comment: These registry values can be generated by GPO. There is no difference if you write them manually. The problem is there is no policy in GPO that will do what I need.

Comment: @doenoe I forgot to mention the most important reason why I use *.reg files.. Not every version of Windows has `gpedit.msc`. However registry values created by that program works in every version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I see your issue. I'm not sure only reg changes can prevent your issue. 
Perhaps a (monitoring) 3rd party application will work?

Comment: Currently I am working with [devcon.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I think it will do. I don't see any better way.